# Recursively slicing first 3 elements of an array at every level

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tree

Given the following nested array of objects. Id is unique for all the objects.

```
const comments = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: "First comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Reply to comment 1",
        parentId: 1,
        comments: [],
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "Another reply to comment 1",
        parentId: 1,
        comments: [
          {
            id: 4,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 1",
            parentId: 3,
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    text: "Second comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [
      {
        id: 6,
        text: "Reply to comment 5",
        parentId: 5,
        comments: [
          {
            id: 21,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5aa",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 22,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5bb",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 23,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5cc",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 24,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5dd",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 25,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5ee",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 26,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5ff",
            parentId: 6,
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        text: "Another reply to comment 5",
        parentId: 5,
        comments: [
          {
            id: 8,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5a",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5b",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5c",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 11,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5d",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 12,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5e",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
          {
            id: 13,
            text: "Nested reply to comment 5f",
            parentId: 7,
            comments: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    text: "Third comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    text: "Fourth comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    text: "Fifth comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    text: "Sixth comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    text: "Seventh comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    text: "Eigth comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    text: "Ninth comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: [],
  },
];
```

I would like to get the first 3 elements of every level ,  with a next property. This next property is to indicate if there are other elements after the third object.
So for example , if the array has [1,2,3,4,5,6]. After slicing the first three elements, next should be true because it still has [4,5,6]. if array is empty or has 3 elements such as [1,2,3] then next is false because after slicing this array, there are no other elements in it.

So it will give me back.

```
{
   comments: [
       {
          id: 1,
          text: "First comment!",
          parentId: null,
    comments: {comments:['first 3 comments'],next:true }
       },
       {
         id: 5,
        text: "Second comment!",
    parentId: null,
comments: {comments:['first 3 comments'],next:true }
       },
    {
  {
    id: 14,
    text: "Third comment!",
    parentId: null,
    comments: {comments:['first 3 comments'],next:false },
  }
    }

   ],
next:true //because comment id 15,16,17,18,19,20 exist
}
```

This is what i have tried

```
export function slicingCommentsInitial(comments) {
  let newComments = comments.length > 0 ? comments.slice(0, 3) : [];
  let next =
    comments.length > 0 && comments.slice(3, comments.length).length > 0
      ? true
      : false;
  let result = {
    comments: newComments.map((comment) => {
      comment.comments = slicingCommentsInitial(comment.comments);
      comment.next = next;
      return comment;
    }),
    next,
  };
  return result;
}
```

I keep getting this kind of results which is almost correct. However I would like to change the comments: {} to children: {comments:[] , next:true} . Please do feel free to correct the code or if there is a better way to solve the problem. thank u very much

[image]

Comment: If either of the answers below solved your issue, then you can mark the one that best helped you as correct. This would help guide others with the same issue in the future.

Comment: btw, why do you have to sort the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the first three elements with `.sort()` and `.slice()`, then recursing the function over each comment's `.comments` field.

```js
function slicingCommentsInitial(comments) {
  const ids = comments.map(el => el.id).sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(0, 3);
  return {
    comments: comments.filter(el => ids.includes(el.id)).map(el => {
      el.children = slicingCommentsInitial(el.comments);
      delete el.comments;
      return el;
    }),
    next: comments.length > 3
  };
}

const comments = [{ id: 1, text: "First comment!", parentId: null, comments: [{ id: 2, text: "Reply to comment 1", parentId: 1, comments: [] }, { id: 3, text: "Another reply to comment 1", parentId: 1, comments: [{ id: 4, text: "Nested reply to comment 1", parentId: 3, comments: [] }] }] }, { id: 5, text: "Second comment!", parentId: null, comments: [{ id: 6, text: "Reply to comment 5", parentId: 5, comments: [{ id: 21, text: "Nested reply to comment 5aa", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 22, text: "Nested reply to comment 5bb", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 23, text: "Nested reply to comment 5cc", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 24, text: "Nested reply to comment 5dd", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 25, text: "Nested reply to comment 5ee", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 26, text: "Nested reply to comment 5ff", parentId: 6, comments: [] }] }, { id: 7, text: "Another reply to comment 5", parentId: 5, comments: [{ id: 8, text: "Nested reply to comment 5a", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 9, text: "Nested reply to comment 5b", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 10, text: "Nested reply to comment 5c", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 11, text: "Nested reply to comment 5d", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 12, text: "Nested reply to comment 5e", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 13, text: "Nested reply to comment 5f", parentId: 7, comments: [] }] }] }, { id: 14, text: "Third comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 15, text: "Fourth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 16, text: "Fifth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 17, text: "Sixth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 18, text: "Seventh comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 19, text: "Eigth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 20, text: "Ninth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }];

console.log(slicingCommentsInitial(comments));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was elegant.

Comment: @desh: Note though, that this mutates your original object.  You lose reference to the sliced-off elements.  That may be what you want, but look to Nina's answer for a still more elegant solution that creates a new object with the desired properties but leaves your original untouched.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yup her solution is elegant as well

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach with starts with an object and gets `comments` and `next` propery.

```js
const
    getTop3 = ({ comments, ...rest }) => ({
        ...rest,
        comments: comments.slice(0, 3).map(getTop3),
        next: comments.length > 3
     }),
    comments = [{ id: 1, text: "First comment!", parentId: null, comments: [{ id: 2, text: "Reply to comment 1", parentId: 1, comments: [] }, { id: 3, text: "Another reply to comment 1", parentId: 1, comments: [{ id: 4, text: "Nested reply to comment 1", parentId: 3, comments: [] }] }] }, { id: 5, text: "Second comment!", parentId: null, comments: [{ id: 6, text: "Reply to comment 5", parentId: 5, comments: [{ id: 21, text: "Nested reply to comment 5aa", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 22, text: "Nested reply to comment 5bb", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 23, text: "Nested reply to comment 5cc", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 24, text: "Nested reply to comment 5dd", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 25, text: "Nested reply to comment 5ee", parentId: 6, comments: [] }, { id: 26, text: "Nested reply to comment 5ff", parentId: 6, comments: [] }] }, { id: 7, text: "Another reply to comment 5", parentId: 5, comments: [{ id: 8, text: "Nested reply to comment 5a", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 9, text: "Nested reply to comment 5b", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 10, text: "Nested reply to comment 5c", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 11, text: "Nested reply to comment 5d", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 12, text: "Nested reply to comment 5e", parentId: 7, comments: [] }, { id: 13, text: "Nested reply to comment 5f", parentId: 7, comments: [] }] }] }, { id: 14, text: "Third comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 15, text: "Fourth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 16, text: "Fifth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 17, text: "Sixth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 18, text: "Seventh comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 19, text: "Eigth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }, { id: 20, text: "Ninth comment!", parentId: null, comments: [] }],
    result = getTop3({ comments }).comments;

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```